# .NET managed heap segments comitting more memory than required

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, windbg

I have an ASP.Net MVC application with a suspected memory leak. The IIS worker process is consuming around 2.6GB ram and this climbs throughout the day.

Analysing memory dumps with WinDbg reveals that the managed heap is only 715MB (output from `!eeheap -gc`), yet when I inspect the SOH segments individually, in total they use 2GB of memory (we use server GC, this figure is from summing the region size for each SOH segment via the `!address [segment]` command - all segments have a "committed" state).

Considering the heap segments are using double the required memory, I expected to see a lot of "free" memory in the heap (possible indication of fragmentation), but the output of `!DumpHeap -stat -type Free` shows there is only 38MB of free space. (Thinking about it now if it was heap free space then this would have been included in the total heap size).

What would cause the runtime to commit almost double the required memory for the managed heap, and why does that memory not contribute towards the actual managed heap size?

Output from `eeheap -gc`:

```
...
------------------------------
Heap 15 (0000022c6dec25c0)
generation 0 starts at 0x0000022b21b677b8
generation 1 starts at 0x0000022b21b650d0
generation 2 starts at 0x0000022b1fe91000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
         segment             begin         allocated              size
0000022b1fe90000  0000022b1fe91000  0000022b22f15a50  0x3084a50(50874960)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000022c4fe91000
         segment             begin         allocated              size
0000022c4fe90000  0000022c4fe91000  0000022c50332ec8  0x4a1ec8(4857544)
Heap Size:               Size: 0x3526918 (55732504) bytes.
------------------------------
GC Heap Size:            Size: 0x2aa756a8 (715609768) bytes.
```

Sample output of `!address [segment]` for one of the SOH segments (there are 16 of these consuming anywhere between 110MB and 130MB):

```
!address 0000022b1fe90000

Usage:                  <unknown>
Base Address:           0000022b`1fe90000
End Address:            0000022b`26ccc000
Region Size:            00000000`06e3c000 ( 110.234 MB)
State:                  00001000          MEM_COMMIT
Protect:                00000004          PAGE_READWRITE
Type:                   00020000          MEM_PRIVATE
Allocation Base:        00000227`5fe90000
Allocation Protect:     00000004          PAGE_READWRITE
```

Output of `!dumpheap -stat -type Free`:

```
!dumpheap -stat -type Free
Statistics:
              MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
00007ffad0afa558        1           32 System.Net.SafeLocalFree
00007ffad0afdbe8       33         1584 System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY
000002275fbc27e0   328560     38096454      Free
```

Output of `!address -summary`:

```
!address -summary

--- Usage Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
Free                                    695     7dfa`bffb7000 ( 125.979 TB)           98.42%
<unknown>                              5145      205`1e61a000 (   2.020 TB)  99.97%    1.58%
Image                                  1967        0`143fd000 ( 323.988 MB)   0.02%    0.00%
Heap                                    247        0`09212000 ( 146.070 MB)   0.01%    0.00%
Stack                                   402        0`04140000 (  65.250 MB)   0.00%    0.00%
Other                                     7        0`001c5000 (   1.770 MB)   0.00%    0.00%
TEB                                     133        0`0010a000 (   1.039 MB)   0.00%    0.00%
PEB                                       1        0`00001000 (   4.000 kB)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Type Summary (for busy) ------ RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_MAPPED                              282      200`00cd1000 (   2.000 TB)  98.99%    1.56%
MEM_PRIVATE                            2737        5`20dd0000 (  20.513 GB)   0.99%    0.02%
MEM_IMAGE                              4883        0`1e598000 ( 485.594 MB)   0.02%    0.00%

--- State Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_FREE                                695     7dfa`bffb7000 ( 125.979 TB)           98.42%
MEM_RESERVE                            2083      204`965f8000 (   2.018 TB)  99.87%    1.58%
MEM_COMMIT                             5819        0`a9a41000 (   2.651 GB)   0.13%    0.00%

--- Protect Summary (for commit) - RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
PAGE_READWRITE                         2483        0`891e8000 (   2.142 GB)   0.10%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_READ                       206        0`0e6e3000 ( 230.887 MB)   0.01%    0.00%
PAGE_READONLY                          2149        0`0d872000 ( 216.445 MB)   0.01%    0.00%
PAGE_WRITECOPY                          461        0`0249a000 (  36.602 MB)   0.00%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE                  172        0`016fb000 (  22.980 MB)   0.00%    0.00%
PAGE_NOACCESS                           106        0`00754000 (   7.328 MB)   0.00%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY                  109        0`00392000 (   3.570 MB)   0.00%    0.00%
PAGE_READWRITE|PAGE_GUARD               133        0`00289000 (   2.535 MB)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Largest Region by Usage ----------- Base Address -------- Region Size ----------
Free                                    22c`7f6a0000     7bc9`80760000 ( 123.787 TB)
<unknown>                              7df6`0193c000      1ff`e81a5000 (   2.000 TB)
Image                                  7ffa`cbd16000        0`011b6000 (  17.711 MB)
Heap                                    22c`6b7a1000        0`012c1000 (  18.754 MB)
Stack                                    93`c5c00000        0`0007b000 ( 492.000 kB)
Other                                   227`5f030000        0`00181000 (   1.504 MB)
TEB                                      93`c5800000        0`00002000 (   8.000 kB)
PEB                                      93`c59be000        0`00001000 (   4.000 kB)
```

Comment: What does !dumpheap -stat tell you? If the memory is not in .NET space, then, are you using any unmanaged resources, directly or indirectly? .NET is rarely the only player in a given process.

Comment: To clarify, is it asp net or asp net core? Do you host it in Azure? If so, what compute service? I may have a lead.